# Excel Formula Column Manipulation

Tags: excel

I need to change the value of a column in a formula but I need to do this programmatically rather then manually due to the number of cells I will have this in.

I am copying this formula into hundreds of cells - `='April16-March17'!L30`

When I copy it into the first cell all is good but copying to the next cell (2 columns away) gives me `='April16-March17'!N30 but it should be ='April16-March17'!M30`

Therefore is there a way to change the master formula to display one column reference down from where it thinks it should be?

`='April16-March17'(ColumnValueChange(!L30-1)` for instance.

Is that clear?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Are you copying with copy/paste, or a macro?

Comment: using copy and paste

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When you say "When I copy it into the first cell all is good", do you mean the equation is `='April16-March17'!M30`?
I would cut either the column containing `L30` or the column containing `M30` to where it works for you.

Comment: Is address function what you are looking for? =Address(Row(L30);Column(L30)+1)

Comment: The Address function looks like it might be the way to go.

=(ADDRESS(ROW('April16-March17'!K30),COLUMN('April16-March17'!K30)-1)) That produces $J$30 in the cell. But now I just need to get the value of that cell

Comment: Not clear at all. Why it shouldn't it be 'April16-March17'!N30 ? This is how excel is working, 2 letters after L is N. If you want to preserve L you can add $ character. Is it what you want?